# How to allow user to configure hotkeys in my firefox addon

Tags: user-interface, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk, hotkeys

Maybe it's in some manual page somewhere, but my Googling skills certainly fail me to find the answer or at least compose right query.

I am authoring a Firefox extension and I want to bind certain action to hotkey. Now, hardcoding hotkeys is one of the worst UX things you can do, so I want hotkey to be user-configurable.

There's a well-written page about making hotkeys in addons: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/hotkeys
Hotkey is specified as string in some specific format. There's another well-written page about how to set preferences for addons here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs

But what is the user-friendly way to specify hotkeys in my preferences? Am I limited to string input which forces users to use the hotkey spec format listed in the hotkey module reference above?

This must be the already solved task, I expect that there's a manual somewhere. The UI control allowing to capture key combinations is already existing in all operation systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following related question has an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799233/firefox-sdk-how-capture-users-hotkey-in-preferences?rq=1).

The solution is based on using the special button after click on which we'll start listening for keypress events and thus capturing whatever user input on a keyboard. After capturing we can generate the hotkey definition string according to rules of `hotkey` module and everything'll be well.

A place to put this button on is needed, though.