# Firefox SDK: how "capture" users hotkey in preferences?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In `package.json` I have:

```
"preferences": [{
    "name": "hotkeyPopup",
    "title": "Hotkey for translating selected text",
    "type": "string",
    "value": "alt-Y"
  }]
```

And it looks like `input type=text`. How can I capture user's hotkey combination? This is not cool that user must type by hands words like `alt` or even worse `accel`.

[Official documentation about hotkeys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/hotkeys) say nothing about capturing in preferences.

Comment: I enable capturing for my users. I just have a user click "set hotkey" then i notify them "listening please enter combintation" and as they type i remember the keys. Not hard at all, just a simple addEventListener with preventing default and stopping propagation.

Comment: @Noitidart you made this in simple prefs or on custom screen with preferences?

Comment: Are simple prefs the inline options page? Thats where I did it: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/workspacehopper/?src=dp-dl-othersby

Comment: @Noitidart I installed your addon and open preferences - for `Hop Window` I can set only one key - for example `Alt` - and not for example`Alt + Y`?

Comment: Ah yeah but you can easily listen to alt etc, just do `e.altKey` metaKey, or ctrlKey

Comment: @Noitidart Can you please write in answer the code that can capture few hotkeys? I will add this code to the wiki at Mozilla Developer Network about hotkeys and preferences.

Comment: Ok ill write something up, based on my addon above. Looking forward to your MDN contributions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this snippet window can be a content window (tab/iframe/etc) or xul window (nsIDOMWindow)

Very basic very verbose, no tricks. Untested.

```
function enterHotkeyRecord() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', downed, false);
    window.addEventListener('keyup', upped, false);
    window.addEventListener('keypress', pressed, false);
}

function exitHotkeyRecord() {
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', downed, false);
    window.removeEventListener('keyup', upped, false);
    window.removeEventListener('keypress', pressed, false);
}

function pressed(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}

function upped(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}

function downed(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.repeat) {
        // if hold down a key it fires multiple times so ignore it
        return;
    }


    var key = String.fromCharCode(e.code);

    var str = [];

    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        // user hit escape so lets exit
        enterHotkeyRecord();
        return;
    }

    if (e.altKey) {
        str.push('Alt');
    }

    if (e.shiftKey) {
        str.push('Shift');
    }

    if (e.metaKey) {
        str.push('Meta');
    }

    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        str.push('Ctrl');
    }


    str.push(key);

    console.log('you pressed:', str.join(' + '));
}

enterHotkeyRecord();
```

Comment: I have a file [package.json](https://github.com/vitaly-zdanevich/extension-firefox-yandex-translate/blob/master/src/package.json) with preferences of hotkeys - how can I call `enterHotkeyRecord()` when user click on button in preferences of addon?

Comment: If it's an inline options page, you can listen to your optioan panel getting displayed with the observer seen here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Inline_Options#Display_notifications and then `aSubject` of that observer is the `window` scope of your addon page, do a `getElementById` and attach it.

Comment: Inline option page - this is when my json with preferences not as separate file but right in `index.js`?

Comment: Inline options page example: https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/tree/inline-options that xpi in that branch is bad, but download as zip and install, then go to addon manager then click on "option" for l10n addon row, thats inline pages, i think sdk simple-prefs is the same thing.

Comment: Hmm, once again about your addon `WorkspaceHopper` - I push to `Set Hotkey` but nothing happen (even if I trying to set some hotkey)... But as I remember few hours ago I saw that text on the button changed...

Comment: It's porbably a bug I made that a couple years ago and was new with addon sdk so it was an experimental addon, I went crazy haha

Comment: Is it possible to change `label` of the `control`-button in preferences?

Comment: Dynamically? Yep easily, just give it an id then do getElementById with the aSubject of the observer. Or getElementsByTagName etc etc

Comment: Is it possible only when preferences inline, not at separate `package.json`?

Comment: Jump on IRC let's teamviewer Ill show you how to do it. Im not familiar with package.json but I'm sure with DOM inspector we'll see its the same way.  https://client00.chat.mibbit.com/?url=irc%3A%2F%2Firc.mozilla.org%2F%23jetpack

Comment: Thank you for answer, I little edit your code and accept it - with this I really can capture hotkey, but without changing text on button in preferences I can't really use this. I will think about `html`-page for preferences...

Comment: Use the observer to listen to your preferences page to, the aSubject is the `window`, then `getElementsByTagName` or whatever DOM manipulation to get to your button and change the label. If you want to see html page example see here: https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/tree/html-options